# redux-thunk and handling exceptions inside dispatch results

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, promise, redux, redux-thunk

I have a basic thunk action creator and reducer adapted from the Redux documentation: http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html

```
// action creator

function fetchPosts () {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_POSTS_REQUEST' })

    return fetch('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_POSTS_SUCCESS', items: json }))
      // THIS CATCHES FETCH REQUEST ERRORS, AND COMPONENT LEVEL ERRORS
      .catch(error => dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_POSTS_FAILURE', error: error.message }))
  }
}

// reducer

function reducer (state = { isFetching: false, items: [] }, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_POSTS_REQUEST':
      return Object.assign({}, state, { isFetching: true })
    case 'FETCH_POSTS_SUCCESS':
      return Object.assign({}, state, { isFetching: false, items: action.items })
    case 'FETCH_POSTS_FAILURE':
      return Object.assign({}, state, { isFetching: false })
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

In a React component that is passed the state as props, I check for the presence of post items, and if present force an component level error:

```
const Test = props => {
  if (!props.items.length) return null
  throw new Error('Error!')
}
```

When starting the app:

1. `fetchPosts` action creator is called
2. A HTTP request is made, and after the response a *FETCH_POSTS_SUCCESS* action is dispatched.
3. The component now updates with the resulting *items* in the state and attempts to read `props.invalidProperty.error`
4. This causes a JS exception: `Cannot read property 'error' of undefined`

So far so good.

The issue is that the JS exception from the component is never output to the console. Instead, the `catch()` block for the fetch promise catches the error, and dispatches an *FETCH_POSTS_FAILURE* action.

This has the effect of swallowing all errors in components that were affected by updating the store. A *FETCH_POSTS_FAILURE* state change is dispatched, but this feels incorrect - there was no error actually fetching the posts, but an error downstream in a component using those posts.

I'm looking for a pattern to help separate errors in the async request from any other random error that occurs as a result of changing the state via dispatch.

---

**EDIT:**

Example with the async example in the Redux github repo: https://github.com/nandastone/redux/commit/88ab48040ce41c39d8daba8cc0c13a6f32c38adf#diff-eeb827d44ad03655e63b7e9319a03dd4R6

Comment: By "network request" error, are you referring to an API-level error, a non-2xx response?

Comment: In fetch's example, it'd be an API-level error as non-200 are still "successful" responses. Basically looking for a pattern to help seperate errors directly as a result of the request from any other random error that happens further on from changing the state via the dispatch.

Comment: Sorry, what's the origin of the `props.invalidProperty.error` error? This can probably be overcome by setting a default value for the props, or a default initial state for your reducer.

Comment: That's intentionally a property that does not exist, I'm trying to trigger an exception in the component. Changed code example to be more obvious.

Comment: Here is another example using the redux async example: https://github.com/nandastone/redux/commit/88ab48040ce41c39d8daba8cc0c13a6f32c38adf#diff-eeb827d44ad03655e63b7e9319a03dd4R6

Answer (score 8):

A `Promise.catch` handler also catches any errors thrown from the resolution or rejection handler.

```
fetch('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').then(res => {
  throw new Error();
}).catch(err => {
  //will handle errors from both the fetch call and the error from the resolution handler
});
```

To handle only the errors from `fetch` and ensure that any error thrown by the call to `dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_POSTS_SUCCESS', items: json })` in the resolution handler isn't caught in the `catch` handler, attach a rejection handler to `fetch`.

```
return fetch('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').then(response => response.json, error => {
    dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_POSTS_FAILURE', error: error.message });
}).then(json => dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_POSTS_SUCCESS', items: json }), error => {
    //response body couldn't be parsed as JSON
});
```

`fetch` doesn't treat status codes >= 400 as errors, so the above call would only be rejected if there's a network or CORS error, which is why the status code must be checked in the resolution handler.

```
function fetchHandler(res) {
  if (res.status >= 400 && res.status < 600) {
    return Promise.reject(res);
  }
  return res.json();
}



return fetch('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').then(fetchHandler, error => {
    //network error
    dispatch({ type: 'NETWORK_FAILURE', error });
}).then(json => dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_POSTS_SUCCESS', items: json }), error => {
    dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_POSTS_FAILURE', error: error.message });
});
```

Please note that any errors thrown in React components may leave React in an inconsistent state, thereby preventing subsequent `render`s and making the application unresponsive to UI events. [React Fiber](https://github.com/acdlite/react-fiber-architecture) addresses this issue with error boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

This is a block of code from a fetch wrapper that I wrote.  You'll see `checkStatus` in the `executeRequest` promise chain, which is where I'm checking for any non-2xx responses using `response.ok`.  Since my API errors return `JSON`, I pass any non-2xx responses to `parseResponse` and then `reject()` the parsed error data which is in turn rejected and returned as an error by `executeRequest`:

```
 /**
   * Parse a reponse based on the type
   * @param {Response} response
   * @returns {Promise} <resolve: *, reject: Error>
   */
  const parseResponse = (response) => {
    const contentType = (response.headers.get('content-type') || '').split(';')[0];
    if (contentType === 'application/json') {
      return response.json();
    } else if (contentType === 'multipart/form-data') {
      return response.formData();
    } else if (contentType === 'text/html') {
      return response.text();
    } else if (contentType === 'application/octet-stream') {
      return response.blob();
    }
  };


  /**
   * Check for API-level errors
   * @param {Response} response
   * @returns {Promise} <resolve: Response, reject: Error>
   */
  const checkStatus = (response) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (response.ok) {
        return resolve(response);
      }
      parseResponse(response)
        .then(reject)
        .catch(reject);
    });

  /**
   * Create a new Request object
   * @param {String} method
   * @param {String} route
   * @param {*} [data]
   * @param {Object} [options]
   * @returns {Request}
   */
  const buildRequest = (method, route, data = null, definedOptions = {}) => {
    const options = Object.assign({}, defaultOptions, validateOptions(definedOptions));
    const body = () => data ? { body: options.json ? JSON.stringify(data) : data } : {};
    const baseOptions = {
      method: method.toUpperCase(),
      mode: options.mode,
      headers: new Headers(headers(options.headers)),
    };
    const requestOptions = Object.assign({}, baseOptions, body());
    return new Request(getURL(route), requestOptions);
  };

  /**
   * Execute a request using fetch
   * @param {String} method
   * @param {String} route
   * @param {*} [body]
   * @param {Object} [options]
   */
  const executeRequest = (method, route, body, options) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fetch(buildRequest(method, route, body, options))
        .then(checkStatus)
        .then(parseResponse)
        .then(resolve)
        .catch(reject);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could consider moving your error handler into the previous `then` block.

I wrote a simple demonstration of the principle: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gWzOVX?editors=0011

```
const fetch = () => new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100);
});

const fetchError = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(reject, 200)
});

fetch()
  .then(() => { throw new Error("error") })
  .catch(() => { console.log("error in handler caught") })

fetch()
  .then(() => { throw new Error("error") }, 
        () => { console.log("error in handler not caught") })

fetchError()
  .then(() => { throw new Error("error") })
  .catch(() => { console.log("error in fetch caught 1") })

fetchError()
  .then(() => { throw new Error("error") }, 
        () => { console.log("error in fetch caught 2") })
```